# Pass Rails variable through AJAX to partial?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

In my Rails app I'm passing a variable to this call: `$.get("/parent_submissions/", {submission: d.id}, null, "script");`, and I'd like the `submission` variable to pass through to the partial that is loaded through the controller. The controller action that is routed through /parent_submissions/ is:

```
def parent
    @submission = Submission.find(params[:submission])
end
```

That action loads parent.js.erb, which looks like this:

```
$("body").append( "<%=j render :partial => 'parent', :locals => {:submission => @submission } %>" );
```

And _parent.html.erb simply looks like this:

```
<h1>@submission.title</h1>
```

I checked in my console to see what happens when the get request is called, and it looks like this:

```
Processing by SubmissionsController#parent as JS
Parameters: {"submission"=>"190", "_"=>"1378443591336"}
```

This means that the submission value is not null, and is passing the correct submission id through the request correctly. But when the partial is rendered, it just looks like `@submission.title`.

I assume something is wrong in the controller. Any ideas?

Comment: It's ERB. Didn't you miss something? It should be `<%= @submission.title %>`.

Comment: @Casper - Yup, I feel like an idiot for forgetting. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change `<h1>@submission.title</h1>` to `<h1><%= @submission.title %></h1>` in your partial.

Answer (score 1):

if your going to use the instance variable there is not reason for you to pass it in the locals hash.

So this line:

```
$("body").append( "<%=j render :partial => 'parent', :locals => {:submission => @submission } %>" );
```

Could just be:

```
$("body").append( "<%=j render :partial => 'parent' %>" );
```

If you want to use the locals your partial needs to be the following:

```
<h1><%= submission.title %></h1>
```

Comment: Please ear reputation points so by answering in proper places.

Comment: Carnway, I don't believe the last part is necessarily correct; if he is not using the :locals hash, then he would still need the `@`. Unless I am missing something? If he did use :local, then yes he could access it as you've described.

Comment: The last part is assuming he is going to pass the variable via the locals hash which means inside the partial the `submission` variable refers to `@submission` defined in the controller.